# Can I use a sass extend into a mixin?

Tags: sass, flexbox

### I wanna use an extend into a sass mixin

### I have created an extend name flex then I use it into the centering item mixin. can I use it like?

```
   //making a extend
%flex{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

//mixin for centering an item
@mixin center-item(){
    @include %flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as the `@mixin` is included within a selector and `@extend` is used instead of `@include` to extend the silent-class, opposing to your example.

```
%example {
  example: example;
}

@mixin example() {
  @extend %example;
}

.example {
  @include example();
}
```

Comment: then i could use like this:

Comment: Yes, as long as `@extend` is used instead of `@include` to extend the silent-class.